# Need to enable gd for an older version of PHP

Tags: apache-httpd, php, php5

The PHP version is 5.6, so quite old. Using `apt-get install php5-gd` won't work any more.

I can locate these `gd.so`:

```
/usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgd.so.3 -- links to 3.0.0 below
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgd.so.3.0.0
```

To enable `gd`, I think I have to set up one of these in `mods_available`, `mods_enabled`, etc.

I'm guessing I'll need an alias `gd.so` in a common place which links to one of the above, but where to put it, and which one to link to?

Is there a step-by-step guide on manually setting this up?

Comment: `apt-get install php5.6-gd` how so? If that's the PHP you've gotten via `apt-get`, the same method of installation would still install modules. Are you sure it's called `php5.6-gd` and not just `php5-gd` or something? Also, until you've verified that's really the version your PHP was built against **you must not** just load any libgd lying around on your system. **That will crash**.

Comment: Check [this](https://serverfault.com/a/354488/516371) to see if it helps.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - same deal with `php5-gd`, not available.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity - Thank you, using that link and some research, found a way to link it in. Details below. As Marcus mentioned, the other SO likely won't work, and it didn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried installing `gd` directly, but no longer available:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-gd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-gd' has no installation candidate
```

Also doesn't seem to be available in `ppa:ondrej/php`, which was the best option.

We do have an existing SO, so these were the steps I did to try to patch it in.

Locate the other SO:

```
$ locate gd.so
...
/usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so
...
```

Create a link in the PHP Extension directory `20131226` to the existing one:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/php/20131226
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so gd.so
```

Create an INI file for this SO:

```
$ cd /etc/php/5.6/mods-available
$ echo -e '; configuration for php common module\n; priority=20\nextension=gd.so' | sudo tee gd.ini
; configuration for php common module
; priority=20
extension=gd.so
```

Enable the module:

```
$ cd /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/php/5.6/mods-available/gd.ini 20-gd.ini
```

Restart Apache and see what happens:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
$ cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
...
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/gd.so: undefined symbol: zend_list_close in Unknown on line 0
...
```

Yep, didn't work, but it looks like it found it and tried to load it. Undo everything and restart to make sure everything is back to normal:

```
$ cd /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d
$ sudo rm 20-gd.ini
$ cd /etc/php/5.6/mods-available
$ sudo rm gd.ini
$ cd /usr/lib/php/20131226
$ sudo rm gd.so
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Only solution is to suggest to upgrade to a later version of PHP!